# 3D trigonometry problem with perspective camera?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For a computer graphics application I need to work out what the farthest ground distance from a camera subject can be seen by a downward-facing perspective camera as a function of the cameras angle with the ground (which is at a fixed distance above a central subject):

[image]

I place the camera at:

$C =(0,0,d\cos\theta)$

The central subject at:

$S = (d\sin\theta, 0, 0)$

So the camera is facing in unit direction:

$C_{forward} = (sin\theta, 0, -cos\theta)$

Its rightward vector is in unit direction:

$C_{right} = (0,1,0)$

so its up vector is in unit direction:

$C_{up} = (\cos\theta, 0, \sin\theta)$

Let $h = \tan/2$ of the vertical field-of-view and let $w = \tan/2$ of the horizontal field-of-view.

The furthest point that can be seen by the camera is in its upper right hand corner, the ray of which has direction:

$$\begin{align}
R &= C_{forward} + wC_{right} + hC_{up} \\
  &= (sin\theta, 0, -cos\theta) + w(0,1,0) + h(\cos\theta, 0, \sin\theta) \\
  &= (sin\theta + h\cos\theta, w, h\sin\theta -cos\theta) \\
\end{align}$$

So if we subtract $R$ from $C$ with a coefficient equal to the z-component of $C$ divided by the z-component of $R$, we will get $D$ where the ray intersects the ground plane:

$$\begin{align}
   D &= C - {{d\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}R \\
     &= (0,0,d\cos\theta) - {{d\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}(sin\theta + h\cos\theta, w, h\sin\theta -cos\theta) \\
     &= (- {{d\cos\theta(sin\theta + h\cos\theta)}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}, - {{wd\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}, 0) \\
     &= (- {{d{\cos\theta}{sin\theta} + dh{\cos\theta}\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}, - {{wd\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}, 0)
\end{align}$$

The vector from $S$ to $D$ is therefore:

$$\begin{align}
D-S &= (- {{d{\cos\theta}{sin\theta} + dh{\cos\theta}\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}, -{{wd\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}, 0)
 - (d\sin\theta, 0, 0) \\
    &= (- {{d{\cos\theta}{sin\theta} + dh{\cos\theta}\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}} - d\sin\theta, - {{wd\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}}, 0) \\
\end{align}$$

and so its length is:

$$\begin{align}
f(\theta) &= \sqrt{({{d{\cos\theta}{sin\theta} + dh{\cos\theta}\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}} + d\sin\theta)^2 + ({{wd\cos\theta}\over{h\sin\theta -cos\theta}})^2} \\
\end{align}$$

Does everything look correct?  Are there any simplifying steps of $f$ that could be made (trig is not my strong suit)?

How do I go about inverting $f$?

Comment: I think you should re-formulate the problem to make the position of the camera at $(0, 0, H)$ where $H$ is constant and does not depend on $\theta$.  The second thing you need is to make the orientation of the camera variable, so you need an additional angle $\phi$ to specify that (but this is not absolutely necessary, just for completeness).  Once you do that, you can take the four corners of the projection plane which is at a distance $\alpha$ from the center of the camera, and find the intersection of the pyramid edges formed by the camera center and those four corners with the $xy$ plane.

Comment: @Erinishighclass: But H does depend on $\theta$, the distance between the camera and center subject is fixed ($d$), so when the camera is at a lower pitch it is closer to the ground, and when it is higher over head it is further from the ground.

Comment: From your last expression, after some manipulations we arrive at

$$
f^2=\frac{d^2 \left(h^2+w^2 \cos ^2(\theta )\right)}{(h \sin (\theta )-\cos (\theta ))^2}
$$

Comment: @Cesareo: Wow, thanks.  Can you show working in an answer?  Also do you know how to invert it?

Comment: Calling $x = \cos^2(\theta)$ we can arrive to this polynomial. One of its real roots must lead to the solution. $$ h^4 \left(d^2-f^2\right)^2-2 h^2 x \left(-d^4 w^2+d^2 f^2 \left(w^2-h^2+1\right)+f^4 \left(h^2+1\right)\right)+\left(d^4 w^4+2 d^2 f^2
   \left(h^2-1\right) w^2+f^4 \left(h^2+1\right)^2\right)x^2 = 0$$